# Alternative to Disk Utility mac

Tags: osx, hard-disk, utility

So i'm trying to resize a partition on my backup drive without erasing my data ([see here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262468/problem-enabling-journaling-in-order-to-resize-partitions-on-an-external-drive)).

I have been talking to some of my friends about this since my other question currently has no responses, and one of them recommended I use another program. So therefore i'd like to ask, are there any programs that:

- work on Mac OS X El Capitan
- are free
- I can use as an alternative to Disk Utility (since its not working) to resize the partition on my backup drive.
- I'm ideally looking for one that i can run on just my user without requiring admin permissions to install or run

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [PartEd Magick](https://partedmagic.com/):

- Free, gratis & Open Source
- Runs on Intel Based Systems including Intel Macs
- No installation - you boot into the Parted Magic *Linux based* OS hence you need access to the hardware but not to admin passwords.
- Supports: ext2, ext3, ext4, fat16, fat32, ntfs, reiserfs, btrfs, hfs and hfs+
  plus limited support for other file systems.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not free anymore, you can download the last free version from [here](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/parted_magic.html)